# I used alamofire, but the result is different

Tags: swift, alamofire

I put the value in my url and get the value of true or false text when requested.

```
func getHistoryCheck() {
    let urlString = "http://myphpfile.php?value1=" + value1 + "&value2=" + value2
    print(urlString)
    
    if let encoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let myURL = URL(string: encoded) {
        AF.request(myURL, method: .get).responseJSON { (myresponse) in
            switch myresponse.result {
            case .success:
                print("myresponse: ")
                print(myresponse)
                
            case .failure:
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I put in the request value, these result came out.

```
myresponse: 
success(0)
```

The result of the value I requested should have been false.

However, success(0) came out.

What is the meaning of success(0)?

++ my php file.

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

$value1 = $_GET['value1'];
$value2 = $_GET['value2'];
$query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT id, name FROM nametable
WHERE id='$value1' AND name='$value2');";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if(!$result) {
    echo 'query error';
} else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    if($row[0] == 0) {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        echo 'true';
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Can I do that even if I write it in 'get'?

Comment: Yes, get requests use `URLEncoding`. It's the same thing that you've done (except their percent encoding logic is a little more precise than what you're doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise not manually building the URL with query parameters, but rather let Alamofire do that for you. And I’d suggest retrieving the values associated with `.success` and `.failure`;

```swift
func getHistoryCheck(value1: String, value2: String) {
    let parameters = [
        "value1": value1,
        "value2": value2
    ]

    AF.request(url, parameters: parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("value:", value)

            case .failure(let error):
                if let data = response.data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(string) // sometimes, if there is a server error, the HTML contains useful diagnostic info
                }
                print(error)
            }
        }
}
```

As an aside, I'd add `validate` so that it will catch non 2xx status codes as an error.

---

On the PHP side, I'd suggest binding values to `?` placeholders to avoid SQL injection attacks.

```php
<?php

// https://stackoverflow.com/q/64761452/1271826

header('Content-type: application/json');

$value1 = $_REQUEST["value1"];
$value2 = $_REQUEST["value2"];

if (!(isset($value1) && isset($value2))) {
    http_response_code(422);
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => "'value1' and 'value2' are required.");
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "...", "...", "...");

// check connection 

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => $mysqli->connect_error, "sqlerrno" => $mysqli->connect_errno);
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

// perform the SELECT

$sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT id, name FROM nametable WHERE id=? AND name=?);";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if (!$stmt) {
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => $mysqli->error, "sqlerrno" => $mysqli->errno, "sqlstate" => $mysqli->sqlstate);
    echo json_encode($response);
    $mysqli->close();
    exit();
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $value1, $value2)) {
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => $mysqli->error, "sqlerrno" => $mysqli->errno, "sqlstate" => $mysqli->sqlstate);
    echo json_encode($response);
    $mysqli->close();
    exit();
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => $mysqli->error, "sqlerrno" => $mysqli->errno, "sqlstate" => $mysqli->sqlstate);
} else {
    $stmt->bind_result($exists);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $response = array("success" => true, "exists" => boolval($exists));
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

I personally make sure that my responses are JSON dictionaries, so that I can parse the results for meaningful error messages, e.g.

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let exists: Bool
}
```

And then use `responseDecodable` rather than `responseJSON`:

```swift
func getHistoryCheck(value1: String, value2: String) {
    let parameters = [
        "value1": value1,
        "value2": value2
    ]

    AF.request(url, parameters: parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseDecodable(of: Response.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                if value.exists {
                    ...
                } else {
                    ...
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                if let data = response.data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(string) // if there is a server error, the JSON (or even HTML, in some cases) contains useful diagnostic info
                }
                print(error)
            }
        }
}
```